# Hadoop 2.2 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I wanted to switch from Hadoop 1.2.1 to Hadoop 2.2. In my project I'm using Maven and it can handle

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

woithout any problems, however changing the version to 2.2 in not working as it is not available in the central maven repository.

Any ideas how can I include Hadoop 2.2. in my maven-ized project?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most of hadoop-core dependencies can be found in hadoop-client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this really work? If I try I get "Failure to find org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-main:jar:2.2.0" which is indeed right since hadoop-main is only a pom project.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Hadoop-main is the parent pom project only. It looks like the new recommendation is to use the hadoop-client artifact instead of hadoop-core. Updated.

Comment: I was also stuck with Hadoop 2 and maven. So created a working one on GitHub https://github.com/alexcpn/WordCountHadoop2. This also has the example for Hadoop JUnit test using MRUnit and its maven dependency. All source basically from WordCount example and unit test example

Comment: What would be the best artifact to replace hadoop-core for 2.2.0? Would it be hadoop-client or hadoop-common?

Comment: I tried this solution and it is not working for me. Seems like hadoop-core is replaced by something else.

Comment: It doesn't work for me too, the project shows a red exclamation mark whenever i try to insert these lines in pom

Answer (score 11):

For Hadoop 2.2.0, the corresponding package name should be as follows (2014.05.27):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

reference:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.2.0
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0

Comment: Replacing Ion Cojocaru answer by your answer makes my compilation fail with this message : `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem`