# Compile Hadoop MapReduce on non-cluster computer and run on Hadoop cluster

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I've read a lot of documentation and information about Hadoop, but couldn't figure out how to achieve this simple workflow:

1. I want to **develop and compile** Hadoop MapReduce with Hadoop Java API on my working machine with all installed IDEs, etc.
2. I want to **deploy** and run MapReduce jobs onto Hadoop cluster with simplest possible way (better from IDE)
3. I want to be able to **integrate** these MapReduce jobs into external application and be able to run them transparantly.

It looks like that all developing/compiling/running should by done on *MasterNode* where exist *bin/hadoop* command line utility and Hadoop libraries. Am I correct?

What are the general approaches to developing, running, deploying MapReduce applications? Is there some kind of maven plugin for integrate all Hadoop dependencies into you project?

Comment: Hi, this is a bit generic question, just to get you started have a look on this [article] (https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/setup-maven-project-for-hadoop-in-5mn/) does it help? Depending on the version of hadoop, some might say that the most common dependency used is hadoop-client see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856113/hadoop-2-2-and-maven/19856654#19856654)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to develop and compile Hadoop MapReduce with Hadoop Java API on my working machine with all installed IDEs, etc.

You can watch video 3, 4 and 5 from this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8p7ZYBB5DmRHK3L6aq8Mvcv) to understand
how you can run map reduce applications locally.

It provides information about how you can develop map reduce
applications using STS (Spring Tool Suite - eclipse with spring and
maven plugins)

If you have eclipse with maven, you just have to create pom file with
the right dependencies.

> I want to deploy and run MapReduce jobs onto Hadoop cluster with simplest possible way (better from IDE)

Running hadoop map reduce jobs on your cluster from IDE is tedious.
However you can run hive queries using JDBC.

> I want to be able to integrate these MapReduce jobs into external application and be able to run them transparantly.

You can run it integrating with other applications, but that node has
to have hadoop binaries.

> It looks like that all developing/compiling/running should by done on MasterNode where exist bin/hadoop command line utility and Hadoop libraries. Am I correct?

It is not right understanding that you need to run it on master node.
Actually you should never run any thing from master node. Typically
one should use Gateway node or client node to submit the jobs. Gateway
or client node will have all hadoop binaries and configuration files
but it will not have any daemon process running on it.

> What are the general approaches to developing, running, deploying MapReduce applications? Is there some kind of maven plugin for integrate all Hadoop dependencies into you project?

Above answers explain this in detail

Comment: Thanks with detailed explanation, Durga. After playing around I successfully run MapReduce from your video. But I have one question - when I run from Eclipse/Intellij IDEA, NOT using `hadoop jar ...` - what is it mode? How application runs/connects to NameNode, DataNode? Is ir tun locally in one process with all default settings?